# Uploading file from a web from in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to upload a file from my webfrom, I am not sure how to handle this in the backend.
My model looks like this

```
`from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models`

class RequesterInfo(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    primary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    request_sponsor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_submitted = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time_constraints = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    attachments = models.FileField(upload_to='Files')
```

Am I doing it the right way? Files is a folder in my current directory. Do I need to use MEDIA_ROOT now? I don't find any MEDIA_ROOT in my settings.py? Can someone help me in handling this

Comment: You haven't found it because you have to define what your `MEDIA_ROOT` is in `settings.py`

Comment: attachments = models.FileField(upload_to='Files'
You can see, I have given a path in above line. Is it still required to define MEDIA_ROOT? What is the diference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py that define django where it will store all uploaded files within MEDIA_ROOT folder, So you given **"Files"**  in `FileField` that means django will create **Files** folder in MEDIA_ROOT folder. When you upload any File from your form field that will store in

```
MEDIA_ROOT > Files > uploaded file name
```

Comment: Ok, so is it going to create the folder Files automatically or should I create it manually? And is there any best followed path used fot MEDIA_ROOT directory? I mean in which part of project can i define it?

Comment: Django will create automatic, you need to define in settings.py MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL only. Read below article for understand deeply about media files.
https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/